# to find out big factorial n count the number of zeros at the end

Tags: java

this is my java code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.math.*;
abstract class ccFctrl {        
    public static long countZero(BigInteger a){
        long noOfZero=0;
        long b;
        do{
            b =noOfZero;
            if(a.remainder(BigInteger.TEN)==BigInteger.ZERO){
                noOfZero++;
            }
            a.divide(BigInteger.TEN);   
        }while((noOfZero!=0)&&(noOfZero!=b));
        return noOfZero;
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfFctrlsToCalculat=s.nextInt();
        BigInteger fctrl=new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger inc=new BigInteger("1");
        int num;
        long[] count=new long[numOfFctrlsToCalculat];
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<numOfFctrlsToCalculat;i++){
            num=s.nextInt();
            for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){
                fctrl=fctrl.multiply(inc);
                inc=inc.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
            inc=BigInteger.ONE;
            count[i]=countZero(fctrl);
            System.out.println();                   
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numOfFctrlsToCalculat;i++){
            System.out.println(count[i]);
        }
        s.close();  
    }
}
```

IDE on compiler is constantly showing me error. just can't get why code is not running

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: OK, obvious mistake:
`a.divide(BigInteger.TEN);`
should be
`a = a.divide(BigInteger.TEN);`
as BigInteger is immutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- You are going into infinite loop in your method countZero. Remember BigInteger is immutable, so doing operation on the same, you should reassign the value like:

  ```
  a = a.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
  ```
- Your condition will never get satisfied because of above and hence will lead to infinite loop. You should check for below condition:

  ```
  } while (!a.equals(BigInteger.ZERO));
  ```

Note Aside: Any reason for defining your class as abstract?

Comment: actually codechef was not accepting the code with public class so i had to change the modifier . before that it was showing a comppiler error.

Comment: Ok.. if you think you are able to get now what you needed better close this question by accepting the answer so others can use it later on if they encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is [known programming contest problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL/).

Descrition is [here](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/16512/fctrl-tle) for example.